# jquery function cannot be started because div is on hover

Tags: jquery

hopfully I could explain myself clearly :

I have a lots of divs with spans within them. and when I hover on each div, its lunch a toggle (show/hide) to ('this') a span.
I want to attach a click function to the span, but I cannot get there, because when the div is 'mouseleave', its back to hide because the span is positioned absolute.

I want to make it that when I hover it, its shows the div, and then if I hover on the span, it stays with a delay.

if I go out with both this div and the span, then it hides the span immidietly.

how do i do that ?

thats my jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/BRDt3/4/

```
function xlineShow() {

var x = $(this).children();


$('.art').bind('mouseenter', function () {

    var x = $(this).children();

    x.toggle(100);




});

$('.art').bind('mouseleave', function () {
    if (!flagx) {


        var x = $(this).children();
        x.toggle(100);
    }

});
```

}

Comment: would be a lot easier to help if you provided a demo in jsfiddle.net that includes html and css used

Comment: like this? http://jsfiddle.net/BRDt3/7/

Comment: the idea is correct.  but it still not working properly. (like a long hide and so on..)

Comment: explanation is not clear